# Safe way to get password from PasswordField in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way to safely retrieve the password from PasswordField in JavaFX8 so it isn't saved in memory?

Standard option:

```
String pass = passwordField.getText();
```

isn't enough for me. I'm expecting something like this:

```
char[] pass = passwordField.getPassword();
```

Comment: So you are worried about the password "staying" alive because it might have been added to the JVM pool of strings? I am just wondering: even if you can retrieve an array of chars from the PasswordField ... that doesnt prevent this component from using a String internally; and then you would not gain anything.

Comment: Right, this extends standard TextField, but i hope that exist safe version like JPasswordField in JavaSE..

Comment: I think the question is valid, since using a char array for passwords is the recommended approach followed e.g. by JPasswordField (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword--) and by PasswordCallback (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/PasswordCallback.html#getPassword--)

Comment: @Krzysiek Very interesting; the Oracle tutorial on JPasswordField talks a lot about security concerns; and the one for JavaFX PasswordField ... doesn't even mention that. Maybe you want to write up a bug ticket to the Oracle folks to see what they have to say.

Comment: Using char array maybe is recommended approach, however it's an academic discussion, in real world there is no difference between String and char array. There are good comments at the end of this article http://securesoftware.blogspot.cz/2009/01/java-security-why-not-to-use-string.html

Comment: Even a char[] would not help that much. After entering a password the memory will contain more traces of the entered password than just the value of the passwordfield itself. E.g. each keypress results in a KeyEvent being created which contains a reference to the pressed key. In addition PasswordField has a undo/redo-feature which produces additional copies of the password. In addition the GC may copy the password to unreachable memory locations. So using a char[] for the text property and zerofilling that after use would not be enough to avoid that the password may remain in memory.

Answer (score 1):

As with many things, you can achieve this using reflection. And since you're using reflection, it won't be pretty (just look at all those exceptions), but I think this is the only way for now.

```
public class SafePasswordField extends PasswordField {

    public final char[] getPassword() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Content c = getContent();

        Field fld = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("characters");
        fld.setAccessible(true);

        StringBuilder sb = (StringBuilder) fld.get(c);
        char[] result = new char[sb.length()];
        sb.getChars(0, sb.length(), result, 0);

        return result;
    }

}
```

The `Content` returned by `getContent()` is always instance of `javafx.scene.control.TextField$TextFieldContent` so it's *safe* to access `characters` field.

Comment: This doesn't really achieve the goal since it is copying from the `StringBuilder` to a new array, and so the user's password will still be in memory and can be extracted by a memory analyzer or a heap dump. Swing's JPasswordField provides direct access to the array so that it can be overwritten when no longer needed and protected from such extraction from memory.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what the variable type is (String, char[] ...) **it will always be stored in memory**, until the Garbage Collector picks it up. While I assume it would be a bit difficult, you would have to make a program and read the memory space that contains the variable's data in order to retreive the password. I wouldn't be worried about any eavesdropping if I were you :)

Comment: Agreed - there is a really good topic regarding this http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe?rq=1

Comment: @Tron Very interesting and relevant article! Definitely worth a look.

Comment: But if you store it as a char array you can decide to overwrite the array with for example 0s' once finished using it. As opposed to waiting for the GC to run (that you can't control)